# Solving $\log(x) = vx^α$ for $x$ via Lambert W function

Tags: lambert-w

Sure I can just get an answer from wolfram alpha, but I want to know the steps involved.

I noticed the title equation while reading this: https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1993/03/W.pdf

The paper shows you how to get to the equation, and how its solvability for $α = 1$ implies solvability for all $α \neq 0$, but not how to actually solve it. So, can someone please guide me through the general solution method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introducing $y=-\nu\alpha x^\alpha$ one must solve $y\mathrm e^y=-\nu\alpha$ hence indeed [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) is involved, since $$x=\left(\frac{W(-\nu\alpha)}{-\nu\alpha}\right)^{1/\alpha}.$$
Note: whether this formula can be useful at all is somewhat doubtful.

Comment: How do you get to $ye^y = -v\alpha$? Does it have to do with $W(z)e^{W(z)} = z$?

Comment: Surely, reading this, you tried to compute $ye^y$ when $y$ is as defined in the answer and $x$ solves the equation in your question. What did it lead you to?

Comment: Yeah I see it now, and feel bad for missing it. $y$ as you defined it completes the identity and then it is trivial to manipulate it into the answer you gave. Now, can I ask how you knew to define y the way you did?

Comment: The natural way: I considered the exponential of the identity in your post and tried to massage it into an identity involving $ye^y$ for some well chosen $y$.

Comment: Massage? Is that a mathematical term?